# HDD Space unlocked? Files deleted?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I wanted to know if you can explain me following behavior.
On my local computer I've got three partitions (C, E, D).
The OS (Windows 7) runs on partition C. On this Partition I've got max 60GB Space.
After a certain time, the free space on this Partition reduced to 250MB.
I know this is far to low but as I restarted my computer today I've got 3.10 GB free space on this partition. I thought it has deleted some private files but they are all there and my Temp Folder isn't empty too.

Can you explain me from where the os got these 3.10GB?
I have no clue.

Comment: Has updates are installed and Windows installs additional updates, the data required to remove previous updates are removed, this would explain the additional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are big chances that the space is taken (and freed after reboot) by your [pagination file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagefile.sys), usually located in `C:\pagefile.sys`.

Check its size when you run out of disk space. If that's the case, you can either reduce its maximum size, but preferably free some space somewhere else on your drive.

In any case, you can have a quick overlook at what takes space on your disk using disk usage statistics viewers like [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But I don't have a pagefile.sys file on my C:\ dir. (hidden files and system files are displayed)
I've got just one on my partition D.
Do you also know what happens if the OS partition runs out of space?
Will it shutdown?

Comment: The Pagefile.sys file on the Partition D is 3.1 GB heavy. Was it moved by the OS?
In any event, many thanks for your answer.

I don't know why this got down voted?

Comment: I don't know either why it got downvoted, and it seems a legitimate question to me, although it might be to broad. If the partition runs out of space, nothing dramatic will happen, but you might encounter some errors. To see what takes space on your partition, you might want to use some tools like [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/)

Comment: I will use that.
ty master